# Why isn't this centered fourth-order-accurate finite differencing scheme yielding fourth-order convergence for solving pdes

Tags: python, differential-equations, calculus, convergence

I am solving the dissipation equation [image] using a finite differencing scheme. The initial condition is a half sin wave with Dirchlet boundary conditions on both sides. I insert an extra point on each side of the domain to enforce the Dirchlet boundary condition while maintaining fourth-order-accuracy, then use forwards-euler to evolve it in time [image]

When I switch from the second-order-accurate stencil [image] to the fourth-order-accurate stencil [image]/12.

I do not see an improvement in the rate of convergence when I plot [image] vs an estimate of the error.

I wrote and commented a code that shows my problem. When I use the 5 point strategy, my rate of convergence is the same:

[image: second-order-accurate stencil]
[image: fourth-order-accurate stencil]

Why is this happening? Why isn't the fourth-order-accurate stencil helping the convergence rate? I combed over this carefully and I think that there must be some issue in my understanding.

```
# Let's evolve the diffusion equation in time with Dirchlet BCs

# Load modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Domain size
XF = 1

# Viscosity
nu = 0.01

# Spatial Differentiation function, approximates d^u/dx^2
def diffusive_dudt(un, nu, dx, strategy='5c'):
    undiff = np.zeros(un.size, dtype=np.float128)

    # O(h^2)
    if strategy == '3c':
        undiff[2:-2] = nu * (un[3:-1] - 2 * un[2:-2] + un[1:-3]) / dx**2

    # O(h^4)
    elif strategy == '5c':
        undiff[2:-2] = nu * (-1 * un[4:] + 16 * un[3:-1] - 30 * un[2:-2] + 16 * un[1:-3] - un[:-4]) / (12 * dx**2 )
    else: raise(IOError("Invalid diffusive strategy")) ; quit()
    return undiff

def geturec(x, nu=.05, evolution_time=1, u0=None, n_save_t=50, ubl=0., ubr=0., diffstrategy='5c', dt=None, returndt=False):

    dx = x[1] - x[0]

    # Prescribde cfl=0.1 and ftcs=0.2
    if dt is not None: pass
    else: dt = min(.1 * dx / 1., .2 / nu * dx ** 2)
    if returndt: return dt

    nt = int(evolution_time / dt)
    divider = int(nt / float(n_save_t))
    if divider ==0: raise(IOError("not enough time steps to save %i times"%n_save_t))

    # The default initial condition is a half sine wave.
    u_initial = ubl + np.sin(x * np.pi)
    if u0 is not None: u_initial = u0
    u = u_initial
    u[0] = ubl
    u[-1] = ubr

    # insert ghost cells; extra cells on the left and right
    # for the edge cases of the finite difference scheme
    x = np.insert(x, 0, x[0]-dx)
    x = np.insert(x, -1, x[-1]+dx)
    u = np.insert(u, 0, ubl)
    u = np.insert(u, -1, ubr)

    # u_record holds all the snapshots. They are evenly spaced in time,
    # except the final and initial states
    u_record = np.zeros((x.size, int(nt / divider + 2)))

    # Evolve through time
    ii = 1
    u_record[:, 0] = u
    for _ in range(nt):
        un = u.copy()
        dudt = diffusive_dudt(un, nu, dx, strategy=diffstrategy)

        # forward euler time step
        u = un + dt * dudt

        # Save every xth time step
        if _ % divider == 0:
            #print "C # ---> ", u * dt / dx
            u_record[:, ii] = u.copy()
            ii += 1
    u_record[:, -1] = u
    return u_record[1:-1, :]

# define L-1 Norm
def ul1(u, dx): return np.sum(np.abs(u)) / u.size

# Now let's sweep through dxs to find convergence rate

# Define dxs to sweep
xrang = np.linspace(350, 400, 4)

# this function accepts a differentiation key name and returns a list of dx and L-1 points
def errf(strat):

   # Lists to record dx and L-1 points
   ypoints = []
   dxs= []

   # Establish truth value with a more-resolved grid
   x = np.linspace(0, XF, 800) ; dx = x[1] - x[0]

   # Record truth L-1 and dt associated with finest "truth" grid
   trueu = geturec(nu=nu, x=x, diffstrategy=strat, evolution_time=2, n_save_t=20, ubl=0, ubr=0)
   truedt = geturec(nu=nu, x=x, diffstrategy=strat, evolution_time=2, n_save_t=20, ubl=0, ubr=0, returndt=True)
   trueqoi = ul1(trueu[:, -1], dx)

   # Sweep dxs
   for nx in xrang:
       x = np.linspace(0, XF, nx) ; dx = x[1] - x[0]
       dxs.append(dx)

       # Run solver, hold dt fixed
       u = geturec(nu=nu, x=x, diffstrategy='5c', evolution_time=2, n_save_t=20, ubl=0, ubr=0, dt=truedt)

       # record |L-1(dx) - L-1(truth)|
       qoi = ul1(u[:, -1], dx)
       ypoints.append(np.abs(trueqoi - qoi))

   return dxs, ypoints

# Plot results. The fourth order method should have a slope of 4 on the log-log plot.
from scipy.optimize import minimize as mini
strategy = '5c'
dxs, ypoints = errf(strategy)
def fit2(a): return 1000 * np.sum((a * np.array(dxs) ** 2 - ypoints) ** 2)
def fit4(a): return 1000 * np.sum((np.exp(a) * np.array(dxs) ** 4 - ypoints) ** 2)
a = mini(fit2, 500).x
b = mini(fit4, 11).x
plt.plot(dxs,  a * np.array(dxs)**2, c='k', label=r"$\nu^2$", ls='--')
plt.plot(dxs,  np.exp(b) * np.array(dxs)**4, c='k', label=r"$\nu^4$")
plt.plot(dxs, ypoints, label=r"Convergence", marker='x')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel(r"$\Delta X$")
plt.ylabel("$L-L_{true}$")
plt.title(r"$\nu=%f, strategy=%s$"%(nu, strategy))
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('/Users/kilojoules/Downloads/%s.pdf'%strategy, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: why should changing the order of the difference approximation have any effect on the convergence rate?

Comment: Isn't that what the order refers to? O(dx^2) means the error will scale with the square of dx, right? If so, error versus dx would have a slope of 2 on log-log axes and I would expect O(dx^4) to have a slope of 4.

Comment: The order refers to the spatial approximation order. That doesn't say anything about the rate of convergence.

Comment: @talonmies Can you explain why? I tried this with the fourth-order runge-kutta time differentiation scheme and get the same results. I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Two things. The stay state solution should be parabolic, so using a higher order difference term should make no significant change to the representativ of the error, and the error and convergence, as you define it, is probably much more effected by the truncation of the time integration scheme

Comment: I'm holding the time step fixed at a values guaranteed to be stable by the CFL and FTCS schemes for the smallest resolution. My thinking was that  error from my time discretization should not scale with `dx` because of the fixed time step. Was that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong error metric. If you compare the fields on a point-by-point basis you'll get the convergence rate you were after.

Answer (score 2):

The error of the scheme is `O(dt,dx²)` resp. `O(dt, dx⁴)`. As you keep `dt=O(dx^2)`, the combined error is O(dx²) in both cases. You could try to scale `dt=O(dx⁴)` in the second case, however the balance of truncation and floating point error of the Euler or any first order method is reached around `L*dt=1e-8`, where `L` is a Lipschitz constant for the right side, so higher for more complex right sides. Even in the best case, going beyond `dx=0.01` would be futile. Using a higher order method in time direction should help.

Comment: How is `dt=O(dx^2)`? I tried the same setup with a runge-kutta fourth-order-accurate scheme and get the same results.

Comment: By setting `dt = min(.1 * dx / 1., .2 / nu * dx ** 2)` you get `dt=O(dx²)`. To the second question, one would have to check that the space discretization is `O(dx⁴)` also at the boundary, as errors there will influence the overall error.

Comment: Can you provide a source for the `dt=O(dx²)` point? I thought the CFL and FTCS numbers were for guaranteeing stability and didn't relate to the order.

Comment: I had fixed the time step to the one associated with the smallest grid in the code. If I hadn't done that, I see why it should have scaled with `O(dx^2)`.